# Insert divider in collection

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Need help in rxjava. 
I need to insert my collection "Job", additional object (dividers), but comparing a date to the next object in the collection.

```
private List<JobModel> getList(){
        return rx.Observable.from(jobModels)
                .filter(t1 -> t1.isActive == 0)
// insert code
                .toList()
                .toBlocking()
                .single();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Could you give an example output you'd like to see?

Comment: I have a collection of my active jobs. I need to take the first element of the collection, compare it with the next date ... and if the date is the same, then continue to compare until the date will vary. then you need to insert a new object "JobModel" at the beginning of the collection, and so on, until the collection is complete

Comment: I still don't understand it. How would you write it with plain Java and for loops?

Comment: something like that:

Comment: edit and make it  specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if the source is ordered by the date, you can group by that date, concat the separator to the group and join them back together:

```
Observable.from(jobModels)
.filter(m -> m.isActive)
.groupBy(m -> m.getDay())
.flatMap(g -> g.startWith(Observable.just(new JobModel(g.getKey(), ...)))
.toList()
.subscribe(...)
```

This will yield a list of values where before each day, there is a JobModel separator added.

Comment: by analogy as here:   _jobModels.get(j).getDay() == _jobModels.get(j +1).getDay()

Comment: The groupBy makes sure jobs of the same day go into the same sequence.

Comment: Well it is clear, I have sorted data from a database.I wanted to ask, have rxJava operator for comparison with the next data object ?

Comment: We don't have an operator that does pairwise comparison but you can achieve the effect by applying `buffer(2, 1)` and comparing the two elements of the list manually in some other operator.